# Import variables from another python file

Tags: python

I want to store some data and allocate some variables for it. This variable should be accessible from another python file.

## FILE 1

```
server_ip ="BLAH"
pswd ="BLEH"
```

## FILE 2

```
server =   // server_ip of file 1
password =     /pswd of file 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending where is `file1.py`. If it's in the same directory, use

```
import file1
server = file1.server_ip
password = file1.pswd
```

If it isn't in the same directory, try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"whatever\the\path\to\file1\is")

import file1
server = file1.server_ip
password = file1.pswd
```

Comment: if file 1 is in the same directory your method works, but its not :/

Comment: second method does not work, i get 'cannot import name 'server_ip''

Comment: Did you write the path correctly, without the filename (only where the directory is)?

Comment: Ah, ive inlcluded the file name thats why it didnt work. Thankyou 
Everybody!